# How to delete or create Hair particle system's spline points via bpy?

Tags: python, particles, hair

In Blender 3 it is possible to make some minor changes to the original non-Geometry-Nodes hair particle systems via `bpy`. For example, to change spline points positions first we need to get evaluated object using context depsgraph. Then in this object we can access particles, hair keys of the particle, and change its position via `.co_object_set()` method. Then we need to enter Particle Edit mode and get back to the Object Mode to confirm the result. Like this:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

dg = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
evob = bpy.context.object.evaluated_get(dg)
particle = evob.particle_systems[0].particles[0]

particle.hair_keys[-1].co_object_set(
    evob,
    evob.modifiers[0],
    particle,
    Vector((3, 3, 3))
)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='PARTICLE_EDIT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

The question is: is there a way to delete and create single spline points for the hair partilces in the similar way or perhaps to directly set the number of spline points for a particle? Another approach I was thinking about was to delete the whole spline and to create it again with the number of points I need, but I could not find out how to delete or create new hair particles as well.